# Is it possible to test wait time for page access with Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, functional-testing

I want Selenium IDE to fail a test if the time to access a page is more than 60 seconds and log the time it took to access the page.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is and should happen straight away with the normal Selenium IDE. If you do waitForPageToLoad command you need to pass in the timeout. you can update this to using the SetTimeout call to set it to what you want.

All of the wait commands in Selenium default to timing out after 30 seconds by default.

Comment: Ok. I have another question. Would it be possible to have the code something when it times out instead of failing the test?